# A is an infinite set and $S$ is a countable subset of $A$. $B$ is another countable set, then prove that $A \cup B$ is bijective with $A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> A is an infinite set and $S$ is a countable subset of $A$. $B$ is another countable set, then prove that $A \cup B$ is bijective with $A$

I have started like this:

Since $S$ is countable, $B \cup S$ is also countable. 
So, I can establish, $B \cup S$ is bijective with $S$.
How do I extend this to prove that $A \cup B$ is bijective with $A$?

Comment: @vadim123- Right

Comment: What definition of countable are you using ? See two choices in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set

Comment: Countably infinite

Comment: Recent [duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/944984/let-the-set-s-be-infinite-and-the-set-t-countably-infinite-show-that-s-and-s-u/945006#945006)?

Answer (score 1):

Since $B$ is countable the set $B\setminus A$ is finite or countable; furthermore the sets $S$ and $B\setminus A$ are disjoint. Therefore we can easily set up a bijection $\psi$ between the countable sets $S$ and $S\cup(B\setminus A)$:
$$\psi:\quad S\to S\cup(B\setminus A)\ .$$
The map
$$\phi:\quad A\to A\cup B,\qquad x\mapsto\cases{ x\quad&$(x\in A\setminus S)$ \cr
\psi(x)&$(x\in S)$\cr}$$
is then a bijection.

*Proof.* The three sets $A\setminus S$,  $\>S$, and $B\setminus A$ are disjoint, and one has (check it!)
$$(A\setminus S)\cup S=A,\qquad (A\setminus S)\cup S\cup(B\setminus A)=A\cup B\ .$$
The map $\phi$ maps $A\setminus S$ bijectively onto itself and maps $S$ bijectively onto $S\cup(B\setminus A)$.

Comment: @Christian-Can you please give a complete formal proof?

Comment: @ Christian- 1) How are S and S∪(B∖A) disjoint? 2) How do you prove that B∖A is finite or countable?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: try proving that $A\cup S$ is bijective with $A$.  Then, prove that $A\cup S$ is bijective with $A\cup B$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

$A=S \cup (A\setminus S)$, so use your bijection between $S$ and $S \cup B$, then leave the rest of $A$ unchanged.  The only issue is if some of $B \in A \setminus S$, but you can patch that up if you need to.